# What does 'you'd be' mean?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, phrases

This is the sentence: You'd be really cool Felix.

What does 'You'd be' (You had be) means in that sentence?

Comment: 'You'd be' means 'you **would be**'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"You'd be" means "you would be".

According to [this](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/you%27d) website, "you'd" can either mean "you had" or "you would", but when you say "be" afterwards the meaning is "you would" since it doesn't make sense to say "you had be". Then you would say "you had been" instead.

Answer (score 0):

It means "You would be".

It implies, though doesn't state (as it was likely already stated), some condition that would need to be met, i.e. "You'd be really cool if...", e.g.:

> You'd be really cool if you wore that shirt.